# Hadoop in action Patent example explanation

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

I was going through the examples for patent data in Hadoop in action.
Could you please explain in detail about the data sets being used?

1. **The patent citation data set**
   This data set contains two columns citing and cited patents. *Citing* column refers to the owner ID who submitted the patent? *Cited* column refers to the patent ID which forms the key to the second data set?
2. **The patent description data set** 
   There are number of fields in this data set.
   To form the mapping for this two datasets, is it *citing* or *cited* column from first data set that has corresponding key in the second dataset first column (*patent*)?

Answer (score 1):

Lets clear up some terminology related to patents to begin with.

What is citation ?

> Citations are documents that are linked together when one document
>   mentions another as having related content

Refer to this [link](http://www.intellogist.com/wiki/Citations) to understand more about patents :)

the "patent citation data set" -- This data set just mentions patent citations.

More like saying patent A uses patent B,C and D

> “CITING”,”CITED”
>
> 3858241,956203
>
> 3858241,1324234
>
> 3858241,3398406
>
> 3858241,3557384
>
> 3858241,3634889
>
> 3858242,1515701
>
> 3858242,3319261
>
> 3858242,3668705
>
> 3858242,3707004

Copy pasted it from the book, so here patent number 3858242 cites (uses/refers to) 4 other patents,
patent number 3858241 cites (uses/refers to) 5 other patents

**the patent description data set**  -- is a bit like the master table, it just holds the data for each patent.

Hopefully that clears up a few things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there was misunderstanding in solution of Top K records from HiA book, at section 4.7, which says:
"Top K records—Change AttributeMax.py (or AttributeMax.php) to output the entire record rather than only the maximumvalue. Rewrite it such that the MapReduce job outputs the records with the top K values rather than only the maximum."

The input data set to be used is actually apat63_99.txt file, and the exercise asks for the records with the top K values (CLAIMS) rather than only the maximum. As AttributeMax.py described in listing 4.6 was giving records for maximum claims.